# Open QML Popup from C++ without blocking the rest of the program

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am quite new with Qt and I cannot find how to make a Popup appear from C++ code without blocking the execution of everything else.

The (non modal) Popup is meant to receive an input from the user. Obviously I need to get that password to do some things in the program but in the meantime, if the user doesn't provide the password right away, there are other tasks that can and must perform in the background (and be reported on the main window behind the Popup).

For now I manage to make the Popup show using QMetaObject::invokeMethod() but it's like the entire program is waiting for the password to continue. As far as I know, the invokeMethod is not supposed to wait for any return value, it is just used to call a javascript function that change the visibility of the Popup (or is there some option to declare explicitly ?).

I don't get how to achieve the behavior I want. As anyone an idea of how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Popups are normally modal, I imagine, so if you show one, the application's event loop suppresses input to everything other than the popup.

So you have to set the `modal: false` property on the popup, and then to make it visible set `visible` property to true, programmatically.

To know when the password was entered, connect to the dialog's `accepted` signal. This signal isn't any different from using `QDialog`.

Comment: I already changed the modal property to false and I already change the visibility using a javascript function (called via the invokeMethod in C++). I have two buttons in my Popup which call C++ functions via accepted and rejected signal to get the user input.  I'm already doing things exactly like you suggested but nothing else seems to happen in my program until one of the buttons is pressed.

Comment: Maybe I am searching in the wrong direction, maybe the problem is not QML related and comes from other C++ parts I changed.

Comment: Why would you change the property using a javascript function?!?! Change it directly from C++ using `QObject::setProperty` method. And you may need to show a minimal example.

Comment: I was using a javascript function for debug purpose, from a time where the Popup wasn't showing, so I added a console.log to watch what what happening in the QML. it stayed like that but of course using setProperty would be more clever. I discovered that a command called from a QProcess was not working anymore since I changed something in a config file. The fact that a part of the program is blocked is probably a consequence of that problem. I will close the subject since the question is not linked with the real problem, but thanks for taking time to help.